# Python: why for loop is in the middle of join() function?

Tags: python, for-loop

I don't understand the following code in the `return` statement. How come a *for* loop is inside a built-in function, join(), and not at the beginning in the middle of statement?

How is this working?

```
def randomString(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```

Comment: It is [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: It's list comprehension and the statement should have brackets [] around it:     ```return ''.join([random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength)])```

Comment: @OlvinRoght No it's not.

Comment: @HeapOverflow, yes, it's generator expressions, I know, just this docs is more obvious

Comment: The distinction between list comprehension and generator expression is quite important, because the latter is essentially "lazy", while the former is "greedy".

Answer (score -4):

It basically loops over it stringLength time and in every loop sends a character to inside the parameter, which then add up next to each other

```
return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```

It adds some stuff right next to the string `''`

```
OUTPUT

>>> ayyertffds
```

Comment: This answer does not explain *why* it is possible to write the call that way. It only "explains" the result one gets. Additionally, wording, punctuation and layout is low quality, and you should add comments below the answer.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa ah okay gonna sort it out i think i missed it

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa well turns out my python knowledge is to a point ill try my best but yeah